# tf.train.batch is showing insufficient elements

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I am working on LSTM based models. the data consists of 80000 images. I am using batchsize of 1  and getting the following as error log:

> OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): PaddingFIFOQueue
>   '_1_Train_data/batch/padding_fifo_queue' is closed and has
>   insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)    [[Node:
>   Train_data/batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT,
>   DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Train_data/batch/padding_fifo_queue,
>   Train_data/batch/n)]]

Can someone suggests what can be the possible issue? as the fifoqueue size is shown as 0 for all possible batch sizes I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error doesn't have to do with LSTM, you are getting it from `tf.train.batch`.
You have to initialize your TF local variable along with global variables.
From this open issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1045, it seems that the order of initialization matters.

```
global_init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
local_init_op = tf.local_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(global_init_op)
    sess.run(local_init_op)
    # rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

some of the images were corrupted in the database which was causing the program to run into this error. Removed those images and now working fine.